# Floating span overflows into next list item

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a list of where each item has a name and a number that corresponds to that name. The name should be left-aligned and the number should be right-aligned. The problem is that if the person's name is too long then the number overflows into the next item in the list. I want it to expand the list item vertically like it does with Person With a Really Long Name.

[Here is how my code renders right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzXDc.png)

Here is my code

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 10rem;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 0px;
}

li {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 0px;
  border-top-width: 1px;
}

.float-right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>John Smith</span>
    <span class="float-right">+1</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Person With a Really Long Name</span>
    <span class="float-right">+1</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Another Person's Name</span>
    <span class="float-right">+1</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Gary</span>
    <span class="float-right">+1</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you don't use flexbox ?

Check this :

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 10rem;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 0px;
}
li {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 0px;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

<ul>
  <li>
    <span>John Smith</span>
    <span class="float-right">+1</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Person With a Really Long Name</span>
    <span class="float-right">+1</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Another Person's Name</span>
    <span class="float-right">+1</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Gary</span>
    <span class="float-right">+1</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the option to assign widths to the spans? I don't see an easier way out of this, besides spans are inline by default. What I would do is assign both spans as `display: block` and float the big one to the left and the small one to the right, and then assign `width: 90%` to the big one and `width: 10%` to the small one.

Because of the floats you'll need a clearfix, in this case applied directl to the `li::after` element.

Check the example below:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 10rem;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 0px;
}

li {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 0px;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  display: block;
}


/* I added this to avoid double border for your first element. */

li:first-child {
  border-top: none;
}


/* This is basically clearfix for that specific element */

li::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}


/* This part does the trick */

ul li>span {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 90%;
}

.float-right {
  float: right;
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>John Smith</span>
    <span class="float-right">+1</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Person With a Really Long Name</span>
    <span class="float-right">+1</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Another Person's Name</span>
    <span class="float-right">+1</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Gary</span>
    <span class="float-right">+1</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```